# Rails: How to change CSS/HTML view code on the fly like with jsfiddle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there a way to edit your views and CSS and see the results on the fly like with a jsfiddle program? I can't seem to use jsfiddle when programming with Rails because so many of my views are Rails code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Webkit web inspector, or Firebug in Firefox. You can select any element, edit attributes, modify the css, and change the text on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your web running on a server (localhost works too) you can try [WebPutty](http://www.webputty.net/) from Fog Creek guys to change your CSS and see the results on the fly. It's free for now.

You can read how to import your site [here](http://www.webputty.net/docs/getting-started)